# Extract href or replace link text

Tags: theming, 8

I'm currently setting up a template for comments and I want to use the url from the **parent_permalink** variable but I can't see from the documentation how to extract it (was hoping to use regex).

```
{{ parent_permalink|replace({'Parent Permalink' : 'Link' }) }}
```

Alternatively, I tried instead to change the visible text of the link '**Parent permalink**' by using the *replace()* filter but this converted the entire variable to a string.

I'm kinda lost at this stage and would appreciate some help.

Comment: Can you paste any code you have?

Comment: @Kevin Updated, with the relevant code. Can paste full template if needed.